# Set value of datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've explored maybe 30 threads and my problem still isn't solved.

I have a JQuery datepicker:

```
<input id="datepicker" name="date" class="mydatepicker" onchange="isValidDate()"></input>
```

I simply want to write a javascript function that accomplishes this when called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("datepicker").value = 'certain date';
</script>
```

datepicker is tied to these files:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the `setDate` function of the `datepicker` library. Try this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date()); // = set to today
```

Comment: not working ... I also have this bit of code on the page (maybe this is interfering?):

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>

Comment: I got it!  I added that code to the $(document).ready(function() ... thanks!

Comment: Assuming you have a variable in the right format, `new Date('<?php echo $dateVar ?>')` should work

Comment: When I put an if statement to check the length of php variable passed to a javascript variable, it doesn't work ... can you tell if my syntax is incorrect?

Comment: You're probably best to start a new question for that as I'm not well versed in PHP.

Answer (score 7):

As this is the first post that pops up when you search for how to set date in a datepicker, here's an answer for everyone that comes here trying to figure out how to do it with vanilla JS:

```js
const date = document.getElementById('datepicker');
date.value = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0].slice(0, 10);
```

```html
<input id="datepicker" name="date" class="mydatepicker" />
```