# bootstrap datepicker default view date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to use the datepicker with a specific default date, but somehow this doesn't work:

```
<input class="cal-datepicker" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-today-highlight="true" data-date-default-view-date="01/01/2015">
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: is it even possible to pass the default view date as a data attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31202155/6105873) says, you have to use the setDate function of the datepicker library. Like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date()); // = set to today
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by setting the 'useCurrent' property to 'false', and then set the date after initialization:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});

$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', '01/01/2017');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$('.cal-datepicker').datepicker("update", new Date());
```